# How to get the rows where transactions never crossed monthly limit?

Tags: python, pandas

I have simplified my problem here to ask how to find the credit card transactions where monthly transactions NEVER crossed the monthly limit?

## Question

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cc':[1,1,1,2,3],
                   'month':[1,2,3,1,1],
                   'limit':[100]*3+[110,120],
                   'expense':[110,80,120,90,90]})

print(df)
   cc  month  limit  expense
0   1      1    100      110
1   1      2    100       80
2   1      3    100      120
3   2      1    110       90
4   3      1    120       90
```

## Attempt

```py
df1 = df.query("expense <= limit")
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('cc')

# attempt2
df.groupby(['cc','month']).filter(lambda x: x['expense'] < x['limit'])
```

## Required output

```
3   2      1    110       90
4   3      1    120       90
```

How to do this in a one-liner?

## Update

I have updated the dataframe, where the limit is different for
different customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, to get all expenses in that month.

```
df[df.groupby('cc')['expense'].transform('max') < df['limit']]
```

Output:

```
   cc  limit  month  expense
3   2    100      1       90
4   3    100      1       90
```

Use `groupby` with `transform` to assign `max` expense to each record in that 'cc', then filter out all records that exceed the limit using boolean indexing.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can `groupby`:

```
df[df['expense'].le(df['limit'])
     .groupby(df['cc']).transform('all')
]
```

Output:

```
   cc  limit  month  expense
3   2    100      1       90
4   3    100      1       90
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not one-liner, but it works the purpose:

First find all the customer, whose credit limit has surpassed at least one, and then exclude them.

```py
overdraft_cc = df[df['expense'] > df['limit']]['cc'].drop_duplicates()
df1 = df[~df['cc'].isin(overdraft_cc)]

print(df1)

   cc  month  limit  expense
3   2      1    110       90
4   3      1    120       90
```